# Swift sort array by Bool value and TimeStamp

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array of messages that I want to sort by whether they are unread or not, and their time stamp. These messages will be displayed in a TableView.

All unread messages should be displayed at the top, and then sorted by their timestamp.

Below is what I have right now; but what seems to be happening is that the items are displayed only by time stamp, without sorting them by unread at the top and then unread messages after.

```
let channelsSortedByUnreadFirst = dataStore.messages.sorted { $0.isUnread == true && $1.isUnread == false }
let timeSortedItems = channelsSortedByUnreadFirst.sorted(by: { $0.timeStamp > $1.timeStamp })
messagesTableViewSection.items = timeSortedItems
```

How do I sort these messages by both `isUnread` and `timeStamp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bool` does not conform to `Comparable`. What you need is to extend `Bool` type and convert its value to a type that conforms to `Comparable` like integer `0` or `1` and sort it using its value:

---

```
extension Bool {
    var value: Int { self ? 1 : 0 }
}
```

---

```
true.value    // 1
false.value   // 0
```

---

Now you can use the boolean value when sorting your collection:

```
let channelsSorted = dataStore.messages.sorted { ($0.isUnread.value, $0.timeStamp) > ($1.isUnread.value, $1.timeStamp) }
```

Comment: Wait, what? You can compare tuples and it evaluates the first item as a primary sort key and the 2nd sort key?!?

Comment: @DuncanC Actually since Swift 2.2 https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0015-tuple-comparison-operators.md

Comment: Very cool. I somehow missed that. (Voted)

Answer (score 1):

Another way using [Swift Algorithms](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjQpM_Y8cLwAhVBQkEAHULcANcQFjACegQIAhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fswift.org%2Fblog%2Fswift-algorithms%2F&usg=AOvVaw2q9GcGCAcoaq5bzDU9soo6) `stablePartition(by:)`:

```
import Algorithms

var messages = dataStore.messages
messages.sort { $0.timeStamp > $1.timeStamp }
let firstReadIndex = messages.stablePartition { !$0.isUnread }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Another Way that might be more intuitive but uses multiple passes.**

```
print(messages.filter(\.isUnread).sorted { $0.timeStamp > $1.timeStamp } + messages.filter { !$0.isUnread })
```

Comment: I think read messages should also be sorted

Comment: "All unread messages should be displayed at the top, and then sorted by their timestamp." Its kind of ambiguous language. meh

Comment: I agree, and it would be easy to add should OP feel the need :)